# Filter on all query on DB with ORM Doctrine

Tags: mysql, database, doctrine-orm, orm

I need of something that I not even know if exists. I'll try to explain.

In my project, in all the object about my store, I have a 'deleted' column that I set to true when that element is delete. I want that the records remain in my db, but all the funcion not find that records.

The solution that I'm looking for is globally, not a filter to set on all my queries.

On my project I use Doctrine as a ORM on my MySQL db, so I hope exist something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Doctrine extensions like [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html)

Particularly, you could use [Softdeleteable](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/softdeleteable.md) extension